# Javascript/PixiJS not loading texture

Tags: javascript, jscript, pixi.js

I've been playing with PixiJS and Javascript. Now, I've been following a tutorial with a bunny(http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixi-js-tutorial-getting-started/) 5 Days ago it was working flawlessly on my PC, the bunny was loading.

Now, I'm on my laptop and it doesn't load the bunny - it never shows up. I've tried 3 different browsers. The code is completely the same. The bunny.png is in the same folder, same name and everything. I thought my code was wrong at first or something, so I then decided to just copy paste everything from the tutorial and it didn't work. It's something to do with this laptop, not sure what, running Windows 7. I've also tried running the script with the resources on my Chrome OS laptop and it didn't work.

Anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: Without the code it's hard to tell what's wrong, try uploading it to jsfiddle and post the link here.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get it on jsfiddle.

Comment: But, here's the whole example. [link](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/example_1_basics.zip)

Comment: And here's the code alone. http://pastebin.com/6AtNtpXp

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the full path to the bunny image has to be specified. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zinigor/58N82/) where the example works properly, you can see it yourself.

Here is the relevant part that I have changed:

```
    // create a texture from an image path
    var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(
        "http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/bunnymark/bunny.png");
    // create a new Sprite using the texture
    var bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
```